# writing data to a socket that is sent in 2 frames

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

My appliactions sends through the wire using socket small messages. Each message is around 200 bytes of data. I would like to see my data sent in 2 frames instead of 1. My questions are

1. How to do that i.e. is there a way to cause TCP to automatically split the buffer in 2 frames?
2. Do I get the same if I send my buffer in 2 separate writes?

I am using Linux and C.

Comment: It _may_ send two writes in the same packet if they happen close enough. There are options to turn that feature off though (see the `TCP_NODELAY` option and read about [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).

Comment: "I would like to see my data sent in 2 frames instead of 1": Bad luck, you don't get the choice, and there's no way you can tell at the other end whether it's happened that way or not so it doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to do that i.e. is there a way to cause TCP to automatically split
>   the buffer in 2 frames?

TCP is a stream communication protocol, all data is continuous. You should split your data by delimiters.

For example, in HTTP protocol each separated request is splited by two `\n`.

> Do I get the same if I send my buffer in 2 separate writes?

No, you will receive them as a one continuous data stream. Frames are meaningless.

*Note: Before you receive any data TCP in your application, packets are separated but OS collect and reassemble them. This process is transparent from your application.*

Comment: @M.M: ok. Do you think that there might be any delimiter for TCP/IP or any socket options that might help in framing context?

Comment: There isn't, you should make your own defined delimiter. If your network is reliable and you can control errors, you can use UDP which is packet oriented protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can consider.

1. TCP does have the [PSH flag](http://packetlife.net/blog/2011/mar/2/tcp-flags-psh-and-urg/), that you can set in a packet, that makes TCP push out any buffered data. But this will work somewhat unreliably, because, in theory, data can get combined again on the receiving side. But in practice, you will see the data being delivered separately.
2. You can't really use "\n" as a delimiter, because it can occur naturally in your data. You have to come up with some kind of a escape sequence to use, and escape all the occurrences of "\n" in the data. This can be painful.
3. If you need message boundaries, consider a protocol that supports it. Like UDP. But with UDP you lose guaranteed delivery. You will have to roll your own confirmations, retries and what not.
4. Finally there is [SCTP](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp). Less used protocol, but available in the Linux stack at least. It gives you best of both worlds. Message boundaries, guaranteed delivery, guaranteed sequence.